# I want to make something when done from typing EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

what is the method I should use to type what will happen after being finished from typing in the EditText?

Please use simple statements and use an example with comments of what happens in that line and what to type in that line.

PS

I wish you got the lines above!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add a [text watcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to the text view

## Example:

```
    myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            // Your query to fetch Data
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // Your logic here
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

just add a  texcchangedlistener with textwatcher to your edittext

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

```
  myeditext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
  {
   //do something here!!!
  }

 @Override    
 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
 int count, int after) {
 }

 @Override    
 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,

 }
 });
```

Comment: i didnt see the first answer. sorry about that.